# $\frac{1}{x^2} $ using geometric series vs. Taylor

Tags: taylor-expansion, geometric-series

So I have the function $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2} $ and I want to represent it as a Taylor series [centered @ x=1] (also evaluating at $x = 1.02$). 
$$$$I did it using the standard Taylor series method:

$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{f^n(a)}{n!}(x-a)^n = 1 -2(x-1)+3(x-1)^2-4(x-1)^3+...$$

And I did it using algebraic manipulations to get it to match a geometric series:

$$ \frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{1-1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1-(1-x^2)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1-x^2)^{n} $$
Or:

$$ \frac{1}{x^2}=\frac{1}{1-1+x^2} = \frac{1}{1-(-(x^2-1))} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-(x^2-1))^{n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n(x^2-1)^{n} $$

So these 2 end up being pretty close when using $T_n(x)'s$ but they're not the same. Did I do something wrong?
$$$$
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use your "trick" but in a slightly different way.

To do so, note that

- $\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)' = - \frac{1}{x^2}$
- $\frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{1-(1-x)} \stackrel{|1-x|<1}{=} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(1-x)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(x-1)^n$

Now you get
$$\frac{1}{x^2} = -\left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(x-1)^n \right)' = \sum_{n=\color{blue}{1}}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}n(x-1)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=\color{blue}{0}}^{\infty}(-1)^{n}(n+1)(x-1)^{n}$$

Comment: Ah that's a way, very clever! I see it has to be a shift on only x, not powers of x. I'm not going to pretend I understand why you can't shift powers of x like you would shift a parabola. I mean you anchor a parabola and can add to it and it will still morph to fit the original functions right?

Comment: Maybe that's why my incorrect representation is still accurate to 5 decimal places with only 4 terms (evaluated @x=1.02)? It's not technically correct but it still works, just morphing at different rates? Or is this purely coincidence? Interesting either way!

Comment: @intwarrior Your series gives also a representation of the function. But it is not a Taylor-series. So, you cannot use the standard estimations of the Taylor-remainder. Nevertheless, it may give good approximations.

Comment: Ok, I can see that. That's probably why the professor stresses focusing on the standard Taylor series methods. I'm guessing real life problems aren't going to be simple enough to use geometric/binomial series "shortcuts"

Comment: Actually it's probably because it's center is at 0 which isn't far from 1, more so than some abstract idea of higher degree polynomial morphing.

Comment: You have created an infinite series of functions which converges absolutely for $|1-x^2| < 1 \Leftrightarrow 0 < |x| < \sqrt{2}$. So, we may not say that it is "centered at $0$".

Comment: Ok, got it, forgot about the change in interval. Thanks again for the great help!

Answer (score 1):

The second approach is wrong, since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(1-x^2)^n$ is *not* a power series centered at $1$.

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry maybe my brain is just done for the day, but how is it not centered @ 1? If x = 1 then (1-x)^2 = 0. Isn't that what it means to be the center? Shifting the polynomial representation. I mean because of the x being squared, it could also be = -1 and then you have a 0 also. But as long as you stay w/in IOC, it should be ok right? Hmmm, how would I center it as a geometric representation?

Comment: A power series around $a$ is a series of the type $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n$. In particular, a power series around $1$ is a series of the type $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-1)^n$. Your series is clearly **not** of this type.